# How to dynamically populate multidimensional array?

Tags: powershell, matrix, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I am attempting to create a **n*m** matrix which will complete the following design:

1. Import a CSV which contains pairs of application name and project name.
2. Generate a n*m matrix built from dynamically named and generated arrays whose first value is the project name.
3. Compare each possible combination of application and project against the original CSV and fill the matrix with true or false statements for each comparison which exists or doesn't.

The first loop that I am using is returning an error that I don't understand, that the dynamically generated array name already exists.

**Code:**

```
$Source = (Import-Csv "C:\Users\m012407\Desktop\DataBase 42\DB--Data\APPcsv - Copy.csv" -Delimiter ";" -Header ("Application", "Project"))

# An Array to hold each project by name. 
$projectName = $source | Select-Object Project -Unique
$ProjectArray = @("")
foreach ($project in $projectname) {
    $ProjectArray += $Project.Project 
}

# An Array to hold each application by name.    
$ApplicationName = $source | Select-Object Application -Unique
$ApplicationArray = @()
foreach ($App in $ApplicationName) {
    $ApplicationArray += $App.Application
}

# An Array to hold the Combined values of each EXISTING application and project combination. 
$ComparisonArray = @()         
$ComparisonSource = foreach ($Value in $Source) {
    $ComparisonString = $Value.Project + $Value.Application
    $ComparisonArray += $ComparisonString
}

# The Matrix, eventually n*m as each dynamically generated array is added to it
$Matrix = @()

##loop1 Now defunct
#for ($iP = 0; $iP -le $ProjectArray.count; $iP ++) {
#    New-Variable -Name Row$iP -Value @($ProjectArray[$iP])
#    $Matrix += $_
#}
```

This code isn't complete yet of course, but during testing, it repeatedly fails to correctly add the `Row$iP` arrays to the matrix in a way that I can call the matrix and display. The error message states that variable `row$iP` (for each attempted row, 1-20) already exist.

I have been searching other posts and guides online and am not certain what I have done that would prevent what I currently have from functioning. Evidently I am missing something basic or haven't quite comprehended something so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks to the assistance of Ansgar Wiechers, I have modified my code a little to run on this motor:

```
$Matrix = New-Object 'Object[,]' $ProjectArray.Count, $ApplicationArray.Count

for ($i=0; $i -lt $ProjectArray.Count; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j -lt $ApplicationArray.Count; $j++) {
        $Matrix[$i, $j] = $ProjectArray[$i] + $ApplicationArray[$j]
        if ($Matrix[$i, $j] -match $comparisonArray) {
            $Matrix[$i, $j] = $True
            } else {
            $Matrix[$i, $j] = $False
            }
     }
}
```

Which has the unfortunate effect of making every value of the matrix false. 
I will keep plugging away at it though.

Comment: From your code what do you expect to be in `$Matrix`? On every iteration of `$iP` you recreate a new **variable** and as `$_` is empty there is nothing to add to `$Matrix `

Comment: I was hoping that add the new array to $matrix, but yes I see that $_ was the wrong term to use. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing I would simplify the creation of `$ProjectArray` and `$ApplicationArray`:

```
$ProjectArray     = @($source | Select-Object -Expand Project -Unique)
$ApplicationArray = @($source | Select-Object -Expand Application -Unique)
```

Also, what you're creating is called a "jagged" array (basically an array of arrays with one dimension each), which is not the same as a 2-dimensional array (one array object with 2 dimensions). For your matrix it would be better to create an actual 2-dimensional array:

```
$Matrix = New-Object 'Object[,]' $ProjectArray.Count, $ApplicationArray.Count
```

which would allow you to populate the matrix like this:

```
$source | ForEach-Object {
    $row = $ProjectArray.IndexOf($_.Project)
    $col = $ApplicationArray.IndexOf($_.Application)

    $Matrix[$row, $col] = $true
}
```

Empty fields are interpreted as false, alternatively you could initialize the matrix with `$false` values before processing the elements of `$source`:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $ProjectArray.Count; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j -lt $ApplicationArray.Count; $j++) {
        $Matrix[$i, $j] = $false
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my script to reflect the second set you provided me, and tried to incorporate the comparison array so that it will modify $matrix[$i, $j] to true or false if the correct comparison exists.

Comment: @Yamez It's not quite clear to me how my answer gave you the ide for the code in your updated question. Please throw that away and stick to what I wrote in my answer.